# How to start a jQuery event when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to get an alert to show if a user scrolls within 100 pixels of the bottom of the page. I'm getting /friends to load into div class = social, but I am having trouble with the scroll part. Any advice on what I can fix?

```
<!--Load friends module -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.social').load("/friends");
  });
</script>
<!--Load more videos if scroll within 100 pixels of bottom -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  counter = 2;
  $(document).ready(function (){
    function loadMore() {
      console.log("More loaded");
      alert("test");
      $('.more_videos').load("/more_videos/"+counter);
      $(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);
    }
    function bindScroll(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        loadMore();
      }
    }
    $(window).scroll(bindScroll);​
  });
  counter = counter+1;
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with your bindScroll function. It probably doesn't matters, but why are you unbinding and rebinding scroll? Are you sure bindScroll is being called? Is your page always longer than the window height?

Comment: I don't think bindscroll is being called.  I never see the elements in loadMore being called.

Comment: That just means your if statement is never true. Is your page longer than the window?

Comment: Yeah, the page is longer than the window.  Even when I try the code in the update above, the scroll part still doesn't work.

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. It only runs once and you are unlikely to  be at the bottom of the page right when it finishes loading.

Comment: Yea I realized that after I wrote that.  Here is the full html of the page I'm trying to get work: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1982111

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20785/discussion-between-enrico-and-sharataka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invisible character after this line

```
$(window).scroll(bindScroll);
```

You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/LEdqj). It is the little red dot at the end of line 20